# Widget has a line through it on android studio with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, widget

I'm learning how to make apps with flutter and I'm using android studio with a real phone plugged into my PC to test the app on. However, when I add some widgets like RaisedButton, they have a strikethrough in the code editor. The code still works perfectly fine however. Why is this happening:

[Here is an example of this happening to me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5rIF.png)

This is the first time this has happened to me. What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means that the Widget is deprecated and it will be removed in future versions. You should replace those Widgets with others that aren't deprecated.

Comment: Oh ok, I'll have a look in the docs then.

Comment: I'm not sure as I use VSCode but if you hover over the widget it should have a message that tells you that the widget is deprecated and that it should no longer be used.

Comment: ah yes, when I hover on it, it tells me to use ElevatedButton

Comment: Yeah, that is it. If this answer helped you, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Deprecation is an early warning that the deprecated feature is scheduled to be removed at a later time, a time possibly specified in message. A deprecated feature should no longer be used, code using it will break at some point in the future. If existing code is using the feature, that code should be rewritten to no longer use the deprecated feature.

For more information visit [Flutter Depricated class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Deprecated-class.html#:%7E:text=Deprecation%20is%20an%20early%20warning,some%20point%20in%20the%20future.)

By the way, Your solution is to avoid Deprication warning Use `ElevatedButton()` instead of `RaisedButton()` because `RaisedButton()`is `depricated` and should not be used anymore.